# Nuxt3 composition API dynamic $refs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3

i've got an image loader component, which is getting the image id as prop, normally, i should use the ref like this:

```
<template>
  <img
    ref="foo"
  />
</template>
<script setup>
const foo = ref(null);
onMounted( () => {
    const img = (foo.value as HTMLImageElement);
    if (img) {
      img.addEventListener("load", () => fitImage(img));
    }
});

</script>
```

But how do i do it with dynamic ref?

```
<template>
  <img
    :ref="dynamicRef()"
  />
</template>
<script setup>
const dynamicRef = () => {
   return 'image'+props.imageId;
}

</script>
```

I've already tried to place this inside an array, like

```
const refs = [];
refs[dynamicRef] = ref(null)
```

also

```
const refs = ref([])
refs.value[dynamicRef] = ref(null);
```

But nothing seems to work

Comment: You want to setup image id as ref in img dom element?

Comment: yes, basically, but the goal is to have a unique ref for each image

Comment: You can add `ref="refs"` to the element that contains `v-for`. https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for